# How to handle Indeterminate TimeConstrain

Tags: programming, performance-tuning

I have to use Timeconstrained[aux] first for avoid some bigs calculation that dont need and it use a lot of time of calculate, so i can't do this.

```
If[aux === ComplexInfinity,True,If[TimeConstrained[aux, 0.3]==$Aborted,True,False,Error]
]
```

I need to calculate the TimeConstrined[aux] first and then If aux is Indeterminate or not. Something like this.

```
If[TimeConstrained[aux, 0.3]== $Aborted,True,If[aux === ComplexInfinity,True,False]
]
```

But this doesn't work.

I could use the error of IF[], something like this:

```
If[TimeConstrained[aux, 0.3]== $Aborted,True,False,If[aux === ComplexInfinity,True,False]
]
```

But. 
True: is for Aborted.
False: never enters false.
Error: works like false, so enter when aux is indeterminate and when is not abort, in other words also enter with terms that i need

Only for understand aux:= (a + b)/0, but the real aux is the coefficient of a big equation of x and y in differents exponents.

Comment: Perhaps you want `TimeConstrained[aux, 0.3] === $Aborted`, with a triple-equal `SameQ`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I checked

```
myCheck[] := 
 If[rez === ComplexInfinity, True, 
   False] /; (TimeConstrained[rez = aux, 0.3]) =!= $Aborted
```

with

```
aux := (Pause[0.1]; ComplexInfinity);
```

myCheck[]  (gives True)

```
aux := (Pause[0.4]; ComplexInfinity);
```

myCheck[] (gives myCheck[] )

and

```
aux := (Pause[0.1]; other);
```

myCheck[] (gives False )

I think you should use the idea that values in Condition[]  (/;) are checked and can be used despite Condition[ ] result itself. You also should be careful with rez, which will keep previous value when Condition[] is not satisfied (in next call, for example). Anyway, instead of If[ ] you should use /; for Abort[ ] check.